# How to sort view with rewritten field values

Tags: 7, views

I have written code with using hook_views_pre_render, I only need to have a custom sort handler which can work with the rewritten field values.

Does any professional here has a sample code for a views custom sort handler which works with rewritten values?

Comment: Probably this is the solution for me:

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84920/how-can-i-sort-a-view-based-on-a-rewritten-field

Comment: I need another solution! please help me